# how to get the uploaded file url and name in ngx-input-file

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

How to get the file name after drag and drop the image in angular ngx-input-file.

Please look at the below example,

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Here after select or drag and drop the image , how to get that dropped image name and path. I want that image url.

Comment: Please paste the code you are referring to directly below the text instead of only referring to a link

Comment: I mean, please use links too but as a complement

Comment: Code is there in a link. Its demo only.

Comment: Yes, but the guidelines state "Provide details", your question gets more specific and easier to answer when you pair your textual question with the code sections that actually are relevant for your question

Comment: I have a suggestion for you, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to retrieve file metadata. The `InputFileComponent` class exposes a `files` array as a public property. Each `file` in the array in turn has the following properties:

- lastModified
- lastModifiedDate
- name
- size
- type
- webkitRelativePath

I created a demo based on the link you gave, for you to play around with. Just run the demo, drop an image and then click on the text that says "Log files" and the data will show up in the console. Please adapt the code to suit your purposes.

**HTML**

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div class="container">
        <a (click)="logFiles()"> Log files </a>
    </div>
</mat-toolbar>
<!-- etc. -->
```

**TypeScript**

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { InputFileComponent } from 'ngx-input-file';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { 
   @ViewChild(InputFileComponent) 
   private InputFileComponent: InputFileComponent; 

   logFiles() { console.log(this.InputFileComponent.files); } 
}
```

**Demo**

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file-8majyc)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the first uploaded file Name and other properties then just do something like this:

HTML:

```
<input-file fileLimit="1" fileAccept="image/*" (change)="fileUpload($event)"></input-file>
```

Function:

```
fileUpload() {
    this.fileData = <File>this.InputFileComponent.files[0].file;
    if (this.fileData !== null) {
      ---call some other function---
   }    
}
```

You can also refere to the examle in their official [Github Page](https://github.com/rsaenen/ngx-input-file).

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML should be like this :

```
<input-file (change)="drop()"
    inputId="files"
    placeholder="My files"
    [(ngModel)]="file">
</input-file>
```

In Your ts file you define `drop()` function :

```
drop(): void {

    console.log( this.file);

}
```

Comment: file will be undefined in your example